# Iterate through the prolog list and return a list with indexes of all positive values

Tags: prolog

I need to get each index of all positive elements in the list and create a new list with all of these indexes

For example,

```
[-1,2,-5] -> [1]
[1,2,-5] -> [0,1]
```

I've already had a predicate to get index, but I do not understand how to iterate through each value and return a list at the end. Right now my predicates looks like

```
indexOf([Element|_], Element, 0) :- !.
indexOf([_|Tail], Element, Index) :-
  indexOf(Tail, Element, Index1),
  !,
  Index is Index1+1.

iterate([],Res) :- Res.
iterate([H|T],Res) :- 
    H>0,
    indexOf([H|T],H,Ind),
    append([],[Ind],Res),
    iterate(T,Res).

iterate([H|T],Res) :- 
    H=<0,
    iterate(T,Res).
```

But after compilation, I receive this error

```
**Input** 
iterate([-1,-2,3],X).

**Output**

Sandbox restriction!
Could not derive which predicate may be called from
      call(C)
      iterate([],A)
      iterate([3],A)
      iterate([-2,3],A)
      iterate([-1,-2,3],A)
```

Pls, tell me, what I'm doing wrong? And why this error appears

Answer (score 1):

You are using Prolog wrongly:

```
iterate([],Res) :- Res.
```

will *call* the term bound to `Res` (hopefully the name of a predicate), but not *return* `Res`.

SWISH will not let you perform wild calls about which it cannot determine that they are safe, hence the error.

But why such complex code? Do as specified:

```
% ---
% gimme_positives(List,Positive)
% gimme_positives_2(Idx,List,Positive)
% ---

% We call this

gimme_positives(List,Indexes) :-
   gimme_positives_2(0,List,Indexes).

% This is the "helper" which additionally needs an index

gimme_positives_2(_,[],[]).                  % If List empty, we are done.

gimme_positives_2(Idx,[L|Ls],[Idx|More]) :-  % Case of L positive
   L >= 0,
   IdxPlus is Idx+1,
   gimme_positives_2(IdxPlus,Ls,More).       % recursive call

gimme_positives_2(Idx,[L|Ls],More) :-        % Case of L negative
   L < 0,
   IdxPlus is Idx+1,
   gimme_positives_2(IdxPlus,Ls,More).       % recursive call
```

Then:

```
?- gimme_positives([],X).
X = [] ;
false.

?- gimme_positives([-1,2,-5],X).
X = [1] ;
false.

?- gimme_positives([1,2,-5],X).
X = [0,1] ;
false.
```

This is actually a case for [`foldl/4`](https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/blob/master/swipl_notes/about_foldl/README.md) ... once you feel at home with higher-order predicates and composing lists:

```
gimme_positives_foldl(List,Indexes) :-
   foldl(
      selector,
      List,               % the list of integers        
      [0,Indexes],        % the initial value: index 0 as first, and the RESULT list as second element 
      [_FinalIndex,[]]).  % the final value: an index we don't care about and the termination of the result list: []

selector(L,[Idx,[Idx|More]],[IdxPlus,More]) :-
   L >= 0,
   IdxPlus is Idx+1.

selector(L,[Idx,More],[IdxPlus,More]) :-
   L < 0,
   IdxPlus is Idx+1.
```

I can't even fully explain why I write the above like that.

But it works:

```
?- gimme_positives_foldl([],X).
X = [].

?- gimme_positives_foldl([-1,2,-5],X).
X = [1] ;
false.

?- gimme_positives_foldl([1,2,-5],X).
X = [0,1] ;
false
```

Answer (score 0):

In SWI-Prolog, you can use the predicates `nth0/3` and `findall/3`:

```
positive_element_indexes(List, Indexes) :-
    findall(Index, 
            (nth0(Index, List, Element), Element > 0),
            Indexes).
```

Some examples:

```
?- positive_element_indexes([1,-2,3,-4,5], Indexes).
Indexes = [0, 2, 4].

?- positive_element_indexes([-1,-2,3], Indexes).
Indexes = [2].

?- positive_element_indexes([-1,2,3], Indexes).
Indexes = [1, 2].

?- positive_element_indexes([-1,-2,-3], Indexes).
Indexes = [].
```